# Jquery - only in tables of class .stable, hide all rows where the 2nd td has no innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML document that contains many tables.

I want to hide rows only from tables with class *.stable*

Where the row's 2nd td has no innerHTML.

Example html for table

```js
 $("tr").not(":has(td:nth-child(2):not(:empty))").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="stable">
     <tr class="spec_tit"><th colspan="2">Resident Evil 7</th></tr>
     <tr class="spec_cpu"><td class="tdr">CPU</td><td class="tdl">Intel Core i5 4460 @2.70GHz / AMD FX 6300</td></tr>
     <tr class="spec_ram"><td class="tdr">RAM</td><td class="tdl">8GB</td></tr>
     <tr class="spec_gra"><td class="tdr">Graphics</td><td class="tdl"><strong>2GB</strong>, nVidia GeForce GTX 760 / AMD Radeon R7 260x</td></tr>
     <tr class="spec_sha"><td class="tdr">Shader Model</td><td class="tdl"></td></tr>
     <tr class="spec_dis"><td class="tdr">Disk space</td><td class="tdl">24GB</td></tr>
     <tr class="spec_aud"><td class="tdr">Audio</td><td class="tdl">DX 9.0c</td></tr>
     <tr class="spec_per"><td class="tdr">Peripherals</td><td class="tdl"></td></tr>
     <tr class="spec_os"><td class="tdr">OS</td><td class="tdl">Win7 x64, Win8 x64, Win8.1 x64, Win10 x64</td></tr>
     <tr class="spec_dx"><td class="tdr">DX ver</td><td class="tdl">11</td></tr>
    </table>
```

But:

1. It operates on all tables regardless of class
2. It includes rows that have a single th (and no td's), such as the first row of the example above

The correct jquery would hide only rows 5, 7 & 8 in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to select all tables with **stable** class with a 2" td empty the selector is:

```
$('table.stable td:nth-child(2):empty')
```

In order to hide the whole row the code is:

```
$('table.stable td:nth-child(2):empty').closest('tr').hide()
```

For more details see [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), [:empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) and [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```js
$('table.stable td:nth-child(2):empty').closest('tr').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="stable">
    <tr class="spec_tit">
        <th colspan="2">Resident Evil 7</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec_cpu">
        <td class="tdr">CPU</td>
        <td class="tdl">Intel Core i5 4460 @2.70GHz / AMD FX 6300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec_ram">
        <td class="tdr">RAM</td>
        <td class="tdl">8GB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec_gra">
        <td class="tdr">Graphics</td>
        <td class="tdl"><strong>2GB</strong>, nVidia GeForce GTX 760 / AMD Radeon R7 260x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec_sha">
        <td class="tdr">Shader Model</td>
        <td class="tdl"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec_dis">
        <td class="tdr">Disk space</td>
        <td class="tdl">24GB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec_aud">
        <td class="tdr">Audio</td>
        <td class="tdl">DX 9.0c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec_per">
        <td class="tdr">Peripherals</td>
        <td class="tdl"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec_os">
        <td class="tdr">OS</td>
        <td class="tdl">Win7 x64, Win8 x64, Win8.1 x64, Win10 x64</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec_dx">
        <td class="tdr">DX ver</td>
        <td class="tdl">11</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```